# error "security token included in the request is invalid" from AWS Client

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis

Hi I'm using Kinesis as my data buffer, and I got this error below, indicating that my **access key** is invalid. I tried to google around, and other posting answers suggest to change the access key to be the right one.

But my case is somehow special, **this error comes at run-time, which means the access key is correct when my application started but after running for some time the access key is invalid all of a sudden.**

I suspect "AmazonCloudWatch" and "AmazonDynamoDBv2" service client library is causing the problem? Or my way to create "AmazonKinesisClient" is not correct?

I'm not authorized to post thread under these two service on AWS forum, so I post it here. Thank you very much.

Scala code to initiate AmazonKinesisClient:

```
  val awsCredentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()
  val kinesisClient = new AmazonKinesisClient(awsCredentialsProvider)
```

error msg:

```
15/10/21 17:05:48 INFO CWPublisherRunnable: Successfully published 20 datums.
15/10/21 17:05:49 INFO CWPublisherRunnable: Successfully published 3 datums.
15/10/21 17:05:59 INFO CWPublisherRunnable: Successfully published 18 datums.
15/10/21 17:06:00 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 115350
15/10/21 17:06:00 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 115349
15/10/21 17:06:00 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 115348
15/10/21 17:06:00 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3016) called with curMem=40094, maxMem=186832650
15/10/21 17:06:00 INFO MemoryStore: Block input-0-1445447160600 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.9 KB, free 178.1 MB)
15/10/21 17:06:00 INFO BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1445447160600
15/10/21 17:06:05 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2792) called with curMem=43110, maxMem=186832650
15/10/21 17:06:05 INFO MemoryStore: Block input-0-1445447165600 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.7 KB, free 178.1 MB)
15/10/21 17:06:05 INFO BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1445447165600
15/10/21 17:06:09 INFO CWPublisherRunnable: Successfully published 20 datums.
15/10/21 17:06:09 INFO CWPublisherRunnable: Successfully published 5 datums.
15/10/21 17:06:12 INFO Worker: Current stream shard assignments: shardId-000000000001, shardId-000000000000
15/10/21 17:06:12 INFO Worker: Sleeping ...
15/10/21 17:06:18 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 115354
15/10/21 17:06:18 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 115353
15/10/21 17:06:18 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 115352
15/10/21 17:06:19 INFO CWPublisherRunnable: Successfully published 18 datums.
15/10/21 17:06:21 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2536) called with curMem=45902, maxMem=186832650
15/10/21 17:06:21 INFO MemoryStore: Block input-0-1445447181600 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.5 KB, free 178.1 MB)
15/10/21 17:06:21 INFO BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1445447181600
15/10/21 17:06:29 INFO CWPublisherRunnable: Successfully published 20 datums.
15/10/21 17:06:30 WARN CWPublisherRunnable: Could not publish 5 datums to CloudWatch
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonCloudWatch; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: 12560958-7816-11e5-8781-e3e348826d8f)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:886)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:484)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:256)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient.invoke(AmazonCloudWatchClient.java:883)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient.putMetricData(AmazonCloudWatchClient.java:354)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.metrics.impl.DefaultCWMetricsPublisher.publishMetrics(DefaultCWMetricsPublisher.java:63)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.metrics.impl.CWPublisherRunnable.runOnce(CWPublisherRunnable.java:129)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.metrics.impl.CWPublisherRunnable.run(CWPublisherRunnable.java:75)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
15/10/21 17:06:31 ERROR LeaseCoordinator: LeasingException encountered in lease renewing thread
com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.exceptions.DependencyException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: P76PVB575SQUA5QPDTD4BSDDTJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseManager.convertAndRethrowExceptions(LeaseManager.java:557)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseManager.renewLease(LeaseManager.java:371)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseRenewer.renewLease(LeaseRenewer.java:102)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseRenewer.renewLeases(LeaseRenewer.java:83)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseCoordinator.runRenewer(LeaseCoordinator.java:194)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseCoordinator$RenewerRunnable.run(LeaseCoordinator.java:130)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: P76PVB575SQUA5QPDTD4BSDDTJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:886)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:484)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:256)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2908)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1256)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseManager.renewLease(LeaseManager.java:362)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: sounds like an issue with STS credential refresh. if you're on an EC2 instance and using a role, you will get the credentials from that role. It's a (access key, secret key, token) triple that can be used to auth and expires. Normally the client should renew (either manually or automatically) the credentials when the are rotated by EC2

Comment: my application starts working with no exception just now, I did not do anything and didn't stop it either. I check the log and the down duration is from "2015/10/21 17:06:45" to "2015/10/21 17:41:30". So I guess the credential refresh will take some time to finish and during this period the "key invalid" error will keep on poping up?

Comment: the credentials are rotated underneath by EC2. you should not experience any down time. the way to works is that the old credentials are valid for a period of time after the rotation happens. what you are seeing is the old credentials actually expiring.

Comment: Thanks a for explanation. As I understand, when this error happens, I should renew the access key on my side? is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: @keypoint It looks like from the code you provided you are using the `awsCredentialsProvider`, which is a `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain`, which should make use of the `InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` if the other providers aren't available first. There will be some overlap so that the old credentials still work for a little bit before the new credentials are retrieved. How are you trying to provide your access keys to the client?

Comment: @mkobit the code is just following an example online and I'm not clear about the classes hierarchy . I just put access key under "~/.aws" and this class will search for access key under this folder. You are suggesting I should "InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider" instead of "awsCredentialsProvider"?

Comment: @keypoint Sorry, I was not that clear. AWS has several different ways to get credentials. Some of them being static where you just enter them in and go, or some of them are more complicated where they get rotated. From your description, it sounds like you may have just generated some credentials in your AWS account and want to use them. Can you link to the online article you are following or explain how you got the credentials that you put into `"~/.aws"?

Comment: @mkobit When create AWS account, the access key and secret key will be in the account information. Basically this class will search for a couple locations for existence of access key

Answer (score 1):

This happens because credentials are rotated and sometimes you try to access kinesis with credentials that are just expired.

The solution suggested by Amazon is to refresh the credentials 5 minutes before the expiration. More details here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/security-token-expired/

Comment: this didn't helped me we use access_id,access_key and aws_session_token , I am trying to run flink code which reads data from kinesis